# Should I put node_modules into a seperate folder when I have more backend javascript files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller

My node js project has the following structure :

```
app
|
|-public
|  |-assets
|
|-node_modules
|
|-views
|
|-index.js
```

**I have lot of code in index.js . So I decided to divide them into different files and put them inside a folder named `controllers`. But since the modules refer to node_modules folder which is not present in the `controllers` folder , I am getting modules not found**

So is it a good idea to move `node_modules` folder inside the `controllers` folder or is there any better efficient method to manage a lot of backend js files with or without putting them into a single folder.

> IF at all I move the `node_modules` into `controllers` is there any chance that I might fall into a trap while developing the app later down the road ? ( This is a huge project . So asking ).

I know that I can directly include those modules in index.js by giving `require("./controllers/module.js")` but the module itself relies on many node modules .So i need to have access to node_modules.

Comment: Where is `controller` (or `controllers`? you’ve used both in the question)? If it’s `app/controller`, modules within should have no trouble using `app/node_modules`. Please post your errors. (And no, you should definitely not move `node_modules` to a different place. It should always be beside `package.json`.)

Comment: You should update your question with information about where your `controllers` folder is, and how you are requesting libraries from node_modules

Comment: 1. use own module in index.js: `import ... from './controller/mymodule';` 2. use own module in own module: `import ... from './mymodule';` 3. use 3rd party module: `import ... from 'some_module';`

Comment: And do *not* move `node_modules` anywhere.

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 2):

No. No.
You don't need to move node_modules. It will remain in your project root. And you don't add it into the requires.

Example of what you probably did and **SHOULD NOT DO**:

```
const module = require('./node_modules/mymodule');
```

**Don't do that**

That's not necessary. And if you move a file around you will face the problem you are facing now.

How does node know where to find a module inside node_modules? Here's some article that explains it: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/requiring-modules-in-node-js-everything-you-need-to-know-e7fbd119be8

**tl;dr: change your require and remove the reference to node_modules. Node will find it by itself**